# How do you detect the point of impact between a moving circle and a rectangle?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, game-physics, computational-geometry

If you have a circle C that is moving at velocity V, how do you calculate the impact point of a collision with rectangle R?

I'm asking this and going to immediately answer my own question in hopes someone has a simpler answer. Searching for this question turns up tons of answers to the static case, of detecting whether a stationary circle is intersecting a stationary rectangle, but I can't find one for the moving case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with:

Firstly, we define our objects.

Our circle C has center point cx, cy and radius r.

The projected next position is C plus its velocity, so C2 = cx+vx, cy+vy, r. We'll label this position c2x, c2y.

The rectangle R is defined as left, top, right, bottom.

We are trying to find Q, the center of the circle at the moment of impact.

1. Check if C2 even intersects with R, and stop if it doesn't, as there is no collision. (I'm not dealing with the bullet case where the circle passes completely over the rect in a single time slice, assume this is handled by controlling max speed somehow).

This is done by calculating the distance from C2 to the edges of the rectangle, and checking if this is greater or less than the radius of C2.

```
dx = max(rect.left - c2x, 0, c2x - rect.right)
dy = max(rect.top  - c2y, 0, c2y - rect.bottom)
isIntersecting = (dx*dx + dy*dy) <= C2.r*C2.r
```

The max is so we only care about positive distances, resulting in a dx,dy point that is the nearest point P on the rectangle, found here by clamping the circle's center to the rectangle bounds. We use pythagorean formula to calc the distance: sqrt(A^2 + B^2) = C, but square both sides to avoid the expensive sqrt operation, as a common optimization of checking distance.

If not isIntersecting, we are done.

Knowing that there will be a collision now, we need to determine the point I of impact.

2. Create a new outer rect R2 that is the original R expanded by the radius of our circle.

   R2 = R.left-r, R.top-r, R.right+r, R.bottom+r

At the point of impact, our circle's center point will either be on one of the edges of this outer rect, or it will be hitting on a circle of radius r centered on one of the inner rectangle (R) corners.

We determine these cases as follows:

3. Find the line passing through C and C1's center points. This line is defined by cx, cy, and the velocity vx, vy, which is where C1 comes from. We can actually use the line segment defined by cx, cy and c2x, c2y. Call this segment CV (as it is the segment defined by C's center plus velocity V).

Find the nearest 1-2 sides (horizontal and vertical) of the outer rect R2 to circle C1 by clamping c2x, c2y to R2.left, R2.top, R2.right. R2.bottom. The resulting point will either be a corner, in which case we have a vertical and horizontal side to check, or it will fall on an edge but not a corner, in which case we only need to check that side.

Find the intersection point W of CV and the side. If checking 2 sides, find 2 points, W is whichever one is closer to C (again using the pythagorean distance).

Now, if W is on a vertical side, check to see if W.y is between R.top and R.bottom. That's the inner rectangle. If so, our impact point is

```
Q.x = R.left or R.right (whichever side we are checking against)
Q.y = W.y
```

Likewise if W is on a horizontal side, check if W.x is between R.left and R.right. If so, our impact point is

```
Q.x = W.x
Q.y = R.top or R.bottom (whichever side we are checking against)
```

If point W did not project onto either side of the inner rectangle, we are in the corner case, where our circle is hitting the rect at a corner. We can find this point by finding the intersection(s) of CV with the circle CR whose center point is whichever corner of R we are checking against (from above), and with radius r (same as C.r).

If 2 intersection points are found, the one closer to C is the impact point. If only 1 point is found, we are just grazing the corner of the rectangle and that is the impact point.

Apologies for not including any diagram or live demo, it's late. I might edit this later.

Does anyone know of a simpler way to determine this?

Note that once the point of impact is found, it is relatively straightforward to calculate bounce from the collision:

1. Find the vector from C to Q (which should be exactly r length). Call this CQ.
2. Get the vector T that is perpendicular to CQ (just rotate CQ 90 degrees). This is the line we will be reflecting our velocity off of, it is tangent to the circle at the point of impact.
3. CQ's length is the distance the circle will travel before impact. Find V1 and V2, which are the pieces of velocity V before and after the impact point. V1 = CQ; V2 = V.normalize() * (V.length - V1.length)
4. The circle's final position is found by reflecting V2 across T, and adding to impact point Q. In other words, the amount of distance the circle would have traveled past the point of impact, it travels in a new direction from point Q.

I'm too tired to remember the math for step 4 there, but hopefully the explanation makes sense.